# Cannot destructure property `user` of 'undefined' or 'null'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux

Error retrieving user information with redux.
I want to get the user information (name, password and address of the avatar from the db) and then edit it.

I'm using nodejs, express, react, redux and jwt.

```
Actions/user.js
import axios from 'axios';
import {setAlert} from './alert';

import {GET_USER, USER_ERROR} from './types';

//Get current users profile
export const getCurrentUser = () => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/users/me');

        dispatch({
            type: GET_USER,
            payload: res.data
        });
    } catch (err) {
        dispatch({
            type:USER_ERROR,
            payload:{msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status}
        });
    }
};

Reducers/user.js
import {GET_USER, USER_ERROR, CLEAR_USER} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    user: null,
    users: [],
    loading: true,
    error: {}
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    const {type, payload} = action;
    switch(type){
        case GET_USER:
        return{
            ...state,
            loading:false,
            user:payload
        };
        case USER_ERROR:
            return{
            ...state,
            error:payload,
            loading: false
        };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

Components/edituser/EditUser.js
import React, {useState, Fragment, useEffect} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {getCurrentUser} from '../../actions/user';
import {Link, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import Alert from '../layout/Alert';
import InputSelector from '../util/InputSelector';

const EditUser = ({
    user:{user,loading}, 
    getCurrentUser, 
    history}) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: ''
    });

    useEffect(()=>{
        getCurrentUser();
    });
    return (
        <Fragment>
      <div className="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <div className="card">
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-3 d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div className="img">
                            <img className="img-fluid" src={'/uploads/noImg.jpg'} />
                        </div>
                            </div>
                        <div className="col-md-9">
                        <form>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label><i className="fas fa-user"></i> Username</label>
                                <input 
                                type="text" 
                                name="skills"
                                className="form-control" 
                                placeholder="Edita tu nombre de usuario"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label><i className="fas fa-envelope"></i> Email</label>
                                <input 
                                type="text" 
                                name="skills"
                                className="form-control" 
                                placeholder="Edita tu email"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <label><i className="fas fa-key"></i> Contraseña</label>
                                <input 
                                type="text" 
                                name="skills"
                                className="form-control" 
                                placeholder="Edita tu nombre de contraseña"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <div className="form-group" >
                            <label><i class="fas fa-upload"></i> Imagen De Perfil</label>
                        <InputSelector/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-12 text-center">
                        <button className="btn btn-primary btn-block"><i class="fas fa-check"></i> Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                        </form> 
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </Fragment>
    );
};
EditUser.propTypes = {
    getCurrentUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
        user: state.user
     });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getCurrentUser}) 
(withRouter(EditUser));
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRKxL.jpg

The problem always happens when I write user: {user, loading}, when I put another code that I already have done it works fine, but whenever I write that the page fails.

Comment: dispatch({ type: GET_USER, payload: res.data }); Can you show `res.data object` ?

Comment: router.get('/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({_id: req.user.id});
        if(!user){
            return res.status(400).json({msg: 'There is no user'});
        }
        res.json(user);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cannot destructure property user of 'undefined' or 'null'`. This error means the `user data` is equal to `null or undefined` the first time you attempt to *use* the Fetch data from your server. The API call to the server is asynchronous. It's only on the second request that you will get the `user data`.

I see the user that you take as props with redux is `res.data` from the server. I'm uncertain of the structure of `res.data`, what is it? So in your component, you should do the following:

```
const EditUser = ({
    user, 
    getCurrentUser, 
    history
}) => {
    if (user) {
        const { loading, ... } = user // Get another key in user object
    }
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// When you try to destructure action object by default for the first time it would not have contain any keys defined by us, However it would contain default keys that redux provides. While Destructring this object would result in undefined or null because there is no matching key. So destructure inside the condition where it matches.
export const addBug = desc => ({
    type: actions.BUG_ADDED,
    payload: {
      description: desc
    }
  });
// i am dispatching the action in the below line
 store.dispatch(addBug('button is not clickable'));

// below i have destructred the action.payload object

let lastId = 0;
function reducer(state = [], action) {
    console.log(action);       
    switch(action.type) {
        case actions.BUG_ADDED:
            const {description} = action.payload;
            return [
              ...state,
              {
                id: ++lastId,
                description,
                resolved: false,
              },
            ];

            case actions.BUG_REMOVED:
                return state.filter(bug => action.payload.id !== bug.id);

            default: return state;
    }
}

export default reducer;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26311796)

Comment: I have added explanation, hope it helps now.